# Oracle SQL - filter out partitions or row groups that contain rows with specific value

Tags: sql, oracle, filter

I'm trying to solve the following: the data is organized in the table with Column X as the foreign key for the information (it's the ID which identifies a set of rows in this table as belonging together in a bundle, owned by a particular entity in another table). So each distinct value of X has multiple rows associated with it here. I would like to filter out all distinct values of X that have a row associated with them containing value "ABC" in Column Q.

i.e.

data looks like this:

```
Column X   Column Q
--------   ---------
123        ABC
123        AAA    
123        ANQ
456        ANQ
456        PKR
579        AAA
579        XYZ
886        ABC
```

the query should return "456" and "579" because those two distinct values of X have no rows containing the value "ABC" in Column Q.

I was thinking of doing this with a minus function (select distinct X minus (select distinct X where Q = "ABC")), as all I want are the distinct values of X. But i was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this that could avoid a subquery? If for example I could partition the table over X and throw out each partition that had a row with the value "ABC" in Q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ColX
FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN mytable t2 on t.colx = t2.colx and t2.colq = 'ABC'
WHERE t2.colx IS NULL
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b8c5/2).

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to answer questions like this (i.e. about groups within groups) using aggregation and the `having` clause.  Here is the solution in this case:

```
select colx
from data d
group by colx
having max(case when colq = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If any values of colx have `ABC`, then the `max()` expression returns 1 . . . which does not match 0.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, using `IN`?

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7baef/9)

```
select distinct colx from 
demo
where colx not in (
  SELECT COLX from demo
where colq = 'ABC')
;

| COLX |
--------
|  456 |
|  579 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT colx 
  from demo 
 where colq not like '%A%' 
   AND colq not like '%B%' 
   AND colx not like '%C%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7baef/15)